# Newbie to NPM and Node.js here and I'm trying to understand global versus local dep installs and how those are shown in package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass

Okay so I'm really more of a designer learning to code. For a project at work I'm helping out with an Angular project so I needed to learn how to use npm and stuff to install Angular CLI and it's deps.

I have an angular project running. It was super easy, no problem. I didn't really edit very much of the package.json, just some of the basics for adding Angular stuff like ng-serve.

When I switched over to our departments actual project, I ran into some pretty big issues getting it to build. Eventually sorted it out, but it kept giving me an error about sass not being able to compile or something to that extent.

Then I moved back over to my practice project. I copy and pasted it into a sub directory of our full project so that I could begin the process of pulling over components that I had made over to the main project. When I tried to run it again, it didn't run! It gave me a whole bunch of errors basically saying that I didn't have node-sass installed. Which I thought I did. It's listed in the dependencies section of the package.json and even after hitting "npm install" a couple of times it was still giving me node-sass errors. When I went back to the original folder that I had copied practice project from it also failed to run even though I'd not changed that file at all.

So then I thought... maybe I removed node-sass as a global install? I remember when I was looking up webpack tutorials after starting my Angular practice project, reading that it's best to do as few global installs as possible because you want each project to have it's own specific version of the dep before you upgrade them etc.

And I remember looking up my global install deps and then looking up how to uninstall one, but I don't remember if I did that for node-sass or not.

Anyway, once I run node-sass install globally on the other project it also starts working no problem.

## TL;DR

Do npm depencies install locally?

If they are listed but there is no local or global install, shouldn't npm install install it? Or does it not?

If it does, then how come I have node-sass listed as a dep in the package.json file and running npm install didn't fix it?

Here's my package.json for reference:

```
    {
  "name": "spanner-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dependencies listed in package.json will be installed locally (for the project only) when running `npm install`. These dependencies will be installed in the node_modules folder by default.

You can check if node-sass is installed for the project by looking for the node-sass folder in node_modules. node-sass will be installed locally by `npm install` even though it is also installed globally.

You're right that you should have as few packages installed globally as possible, and having a dependency installed globally should only be a last resort temporary solution to your problem. In your situation I would do the following:

1. Remove node-sass from package.json
2. Uninstall node-sass globally: `npm uninstall -g node-sass`
3. Check if the node_modules/node-sass folder exists
4. If it does, delete it
5. Re-install it by `npm install --save node-sass`
6. Verify that the issue is fixed
7. If it's still not working: delete the entire node_modules folder, then run `npm install` again